# ContentEditable属性の中で、現在のカーソル位置(キャレット)が、特定のタグの中かどうか知りたい。

Tags: javascript, android

Android端末のWebViewにて。

例えばですが、以下のようなHTMLの時に
bタグで囲まれている「いいい」にカーソルが移動した時、
何かイベントが起きてくれたらと考えています。

実現したい事は、そのイベントを元に太字設定ボタンの状態を変更することです。

【表示】

  
    あああ**いいい**ううう

【内部ソース】

```
<html>
 <head>
   //略
 </head>
 <body contenteditable="true">
  <div>
    あああ<b>いいい</b>ううう
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

調べてはみたのですがなかなかそれらしきイベントも見つからず、
ダメ元でフォーカス関連のイベントを試したりしましたが反応なしで・・・

そこでこちらに質問させて頂きました。

少しでも情報を得られればと思っています。
どうかよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectionchange`イベントを捕まえて、Selection APIでキャレットの位置を調べればよさそうです。

ざっとコードを書いてみましたが、このコードだと選択した範囲の始点と終点が別々のB要素の中のときでもOKとしています。実用上はOKにしないほうが良いかもしれません。

```js
function updateStatus(msg) {
  document.querySelector('#status').textContent = msg;
}

function isOrInTag(element, tag) {
  for (; element; element = element.parentNode) {
    if (element.tagName == tag)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function onSelectionChange() {
  const selection = getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount == 0) {
    updateStatus('キャレットまたはテキスト選択がありません');
    return;
  }
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  if (isOrInTag(range.startContainer, 'B') && isOrInTag(range.endContainer, 'B'))
    updateStatus('Bタグの中です');
  else
    updateStatus('Bタグの中ではありません');
}

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', onSelectionChange);
// selectionchangeイベントが起きなくてもメッセージ初期化
onSelectionChange();
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<pre id="status"></pre>

<div contenteditable=true>
normal text
<b>bold text <i>italic in bold</i> bold again</b>
normal text again
<i>italic text <b>bold in italic</b></i>
normal text again and again
</div>
```

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます！
さっそく試した所問題なく動作致しました。

今回の件で、JavaScriptの知識がまだまだなのを痛感しました・・・
もっと勉強します。